# Error Installing Eclim, "SKProfile" is not a valid indentifier

Tags: java, sdk, windows-subsystem-for-linux, eclim

I am trying to get Eclim installed on my Debian Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL) virtual machine under Windows 10. It appears that my issues have to do with the SDK in some way, but I'm unsure of how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my log file containing the stacktrace.

```
!SESSION 2018-09-04 15:19:20.348 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -refresh -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -clean -refresh -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2018-09-04 15:19:47.152
!MESSAGE An error occurred while installing the items
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2018-09-04 15:19:47.152
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.ant.launching 1.0.200.dist, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2018-09-04 15:19:47.152
!MESSAGE The artifact file for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.0.200.dist was not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-09-04 15:19:47.409
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "SDKProfile" is not a valid profile identifier.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.garbagecollector.Application.start(Application.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Could you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: having the same issue actually

Answer (score 1):

Try installing latest, Eclipse 4.8.x (Photon), which is one of the requirements in the installation instruction. That fixed it for me.